# Create a class for Merging two image using php GD Library

Tags: php, gd

Do any one have an idea for creating two barchart image using PHP GD library and Merge it using class object with GD Library?

Comment: good idea but look for it on a tutorial site

Comment: @SyedQarib I have seen but no one using class

Comment: then create one using that code

Comment: @SyedQarib i already created i have an error please check the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487010/php-gd-library-cannot-merge-to-image-using-function)